# drools 6.0.1 workbench cannot deploy to tomcat7.0

Tags: drools

I download kie-drools-wb-distribution-6.0.1.Final, and unzip it, copy kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7.0.war into tomcat7.0. 
After restarting tomcat, there is only one error logged in catalina.out and cause drools workbench cannot start correctly.

Error listenerStart 
Context [/kie-wb] startup failed due to previous errors

**Note**: I change the long war file name into simple one so that I can easily access web app. 
I have read the readme under kie-web, it mentioned that I need to copy "kie-tomcat-integration Jar" into TOMCAT_HOME/lib, but I cannot find it in the download package.

The whole error log is following:

信息: Deploying web application directory D:\green\tomcat\webapps\kie-wb
2014-2-11 10:22:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal 
严重: Error listenerStart
2014-2-11 10:22:36 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal 
严重: Context [/kie-wb] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: It seems that you need to find out where Tomcat is doing its logging. The message `startup failed due to previous errors` indicates that there are other errors earlier in the server output, which will explain what went wrong.

Comment: Try to increase tomcat logging level to see what's going wrong: http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/increase-tomcat-logging-verbosity-quick-problem-resolution

Comment: thanks for your information, after enable the tomcat debug level, it seems I went into a terrible world: so many jars are missed, and it asked me to download more than 20 jars, still not finished, and with different version.

Comment: Is there anybody can run the kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7.0.war  under tomcat? So many jars/filers are missed and need to be copied, I really confused how it can be released. Is it possible that somebody share a total runnable package ?

Comment: @richard How do you enable debug-level logging for drools wb in tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

1. You will have to download the kie-tomcat-integration from mvnrepository http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kie/kie-tomcat-integration/6.0.1.Final and place it in TOMCAT/lib.
2. You will also need to download the jacc lib from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc/jboss-jacc-api_1.4_spec/1.0.3.Final and place it in TOMCAT/lib.
3. Add valve configuration into TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml inside Host element as last valve definition
4. Rename org.uberfire.security.auth.AuthenticationSource to org.uberfire.security.auth.AuthenticationSource-ORIGIN and
   rename  org.uberfire.security.auth.AuthenticationSource-TOMCAT-JEE-SECURITY to org.uberfire.security.auth.AuthenticationSource
   inside WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services

Answer (score 0):

Your kie-drools-wb-distribution-6.0.1.Final archive contains a txt (README or sort of) file which has a list of steps to do to correctly install the webapp on Tomcat. Melvins answer contains those steps. Please refer to that txt to be sure you make the correct steps in the correct sequence and using the correct version of required libraries. You also may need to add / modify webapp properties to enable / disable certain features (e.g. demo projects installation) you may or may not want and configure your local git and maven repositories (folders).